# Why 'sort{$a-$b}(list of floats)' doesn't work in Perl?

Tags: perl, sorting

```
$, = ' '; print sort {$a-$b} qw/1.5 2.5 2 1/;
```

Produces `1.5 1 2.5 2`. I know about `<=>`, I just wonder what's going on and if this behavior is documented.

Even this doesn't work:

```
$, = ' '; print(sort{(sqrt$a)-(sqrt$b)} qw/1.5 2.5 2 1/);
```

Something to do with `$a` and `$b` magick, as if they are evaluated as strings. OTOH, list of integers is sorted correctly with `-` instead of `<=>`.

Comment: I don't quite understand why you think it *would* work.

Comment: It works for integers and saves a couple keystrokes. After using it several times I've got a wrong belief that *any* negative or positive value will do. When it didn't work for floats, my twisted reasoning concluded that `$a` and `$b` were somehow evaluated to integers (or strings) *before* subtraction. Very stupid of me. Anyway it's cleared now, thanks to Barmar's answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the Perl [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html)

> If SUBNAME is specified, it gives the name of a subroutine that returns an **integer** less than, equal to, or greater than 0 , depending on how the elements of the list are to be ordered.

If you use `-` with `floats`, it returns a `float` result, not an `integer` as required by the above.

Comment: To demonstrate the point, `$, = ' '; print sort {10*$a - 10*$b} qw/1.5 2.5 2 1/;` gives `1 1.5 2 2.5`.